# Discord.js Bot "guildMember.addRole is not a function"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, I'm trying to change the role of a user that joins a server, but it keeps saying `addRole is not a function`. I'm currently using Discord.js version **11.5.1** so I shouldn't have to use `guildMember.roles.add` correct? I have no idea why this isn't working and nothing I can find online helps solve this issue. If you need any more information let me know.

Here is the code:

```
var Discord = require('discord.io');
var logger = require('winston');
var auth = require('./auth.json');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var db = require('./db.js');
var serverIds = require('./serverIds.js');

// Configure logger settings
logger.remove(logger.transports.Console);
logger.add(new logger.transports.Console, {
    colorize: true
});
logger.level = 'debug';

// Initialize Discord Bot
var bot = new Discord.Client({
   token: auth.token,
   autorun: true
});

bot.on('guildMemberAdd', (guildMember) => {
    try {
        guildMember.addRole('663290242073100309');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(guildMember);
    }
});
```

And here is the error in the terminal:

```
Nicks-MacBook-Pro-2:pokemon victory road bot nick$ node bot.js
Connected
{"message":"Connected","level":"info"}
{"message":"Logged in as: ","level":"info"}
{"message":"Professor Magnolia - (663188794740178957)","level":"info"}
TypeError: guildMember.addRole is not a function
    at DiscordClient.<anonymous> (/Users/nick/Desktop/Pokemon Victory Road Bot/bot.js:65:21)
    at DiscordClient.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at emit (/Users/nick/Desktop/Pokemon Victory Road Bot/node_modules/discord.io/lib/index.js:1580:14)
    at DiscordClient.handleWSMessage (/Users/nick/Desktop/Pokemon Victory Road Bot/node_modules/discord.io/lib/index.js:1904:11)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Receiver.ontext (/Users/nick/Desktop/Pokemon Victory Road Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:841:10)
    at /Users/nick/Desktop/Pokemon Victory Road Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:536:18
    at Receiver.applyExtensions (/Users/nick/Desktop/Pokemon Victory Road Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:371:5)
    at /Users/nick/Desktop/Pokemon Victory Road Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:508:14
    at Receiver.flush (/Users/nick/Desktop/Pokemon Victory Road Bot/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:347:3)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found out my problem. I'm using Discord.io instead of Discord.js smh. I'm new to making bots so I didn't realize there was a difference and the tutorial I was following to get started didn't